# Structure of Java web app

Tags: java, class, web-applications, web.xml

What is the general application structure of a web app like the folder structure WEB-INF, source files,web.xml ?

Also a brief explanation of these files would be helpful?

Also specificall are there multiple WEB-INF folders in an app and if yes, why?

Comment: A web app cannot have multiple WEB-INF folders, because you can't have more than one folder named the same thing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read [the part of the Java EE tutorial about web apps](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnadr.html).

Answer (score -1):

The information you're looking for can be found at the [J2EE tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/WebApp3.html).